# Disable node.js garbage collection for a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, v8

Is there any way to explicitly disable GC runs (at least most time-consuming ones, like GC interrupts in old space) during the specified period of time, while executing some code sensitive to delays? Something like this:

```
disableGc();
runCodeWithoutDelays();
enableGc();
```

Probably using some node options, or native modules? Or can I write my own module, is there an API in V8 for that?

Comment: Hmmm, will [this](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-idle-gc) work for you?

Comment: Not really. This will trigger non-incremental major GC runs (mark-sweep-compact) which are pretty heavy and introduce long delays in comparison to fast incremental runs. Rather than running GC myself, I'd like to block GC for some time and release it again to normal operation.

Comment: I would recommend raising this question as a bug in Node.js repo and v8 mailing list.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Question, do you need to allocate memory during that time?

Comment: [GitHub issue - Disable GC](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/462). Looks like there's no way to do this within a process already running...

Comment: @NickApperson most probably no, if we have an option to preallocate some memory before `disableGc` call.

Comment: I mean, new space size can be fixed during this time. We're fine with a catchable exception that is thrown on attempts to allocate more memory than current new space allows.

Comment: I believe that it is possible if you are not allocating any memory fresh, but there is nothing built-in to node to do that, so you'll need to do some of your own work. On a first approximation, if you don't allocate memory and are running in a loop, Node.js is very unlikely to do a GC.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you can't manually stop v8's garbage collector, the only thing you can do is start the gc process manually running `global.gc()` but not stopping v8's process.

Answer (score 4):

Another person had the same question and published an issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/462

Answer is you can't disable the GC in Node, but you can at least tweak the memory options to use the max space available and delay GC, by using --max_old_space_size, --max-semi-space-size.

An example is provided there in context.